# Unable to click on image in compose android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Hello I am trying to add an clickable image in Compose, but when I tried this it is not working.

When I click on the image, I want to execute a piece of code, but to test added a Log statement which is not printing

could you suggest what I might be doing wrong here please

```
 Column(
        Modifier
            .weight(3f)
            .padding(horizontal = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.margin_vertical_small))
    ) {
        Row {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.user_defined_car_battery_size),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
            )
            Image(
                painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_info),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable {
                        Log.d("Userdefinercarsxreen", "ButtonClicked")
                        onBatteryInfoCLicked
                    }
                    .padding(start = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.margin_vertical_tiny))
            )
        }
    }
```

Thanks
R

Answer (score 1):

In the code you provided, it seems that you're missing parentheses after the onBatteryInfoClicked function call.

Check-out this updated code:

```
fun SampleComposable(onBatteryInfoCLicked: () -> Unit){
    Column(
        Modifier
            .weight(3f)
            .padding(horizontal = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.margin_vertical_small))
    ) {
        Row {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.user_defined_car_battery_size),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
            )
            Image(
                painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_info),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable {
                        onBatteryInfoCLicked()
                    }
                    .padding(start = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.margin_vertical_tiny))
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the `onBatteryInfoCLicked` is a lambda function passed to a composable function and If I'm right the solution is fairly easy:

```kotlin
 Column(
        Modifier
            .weight(3f)
            .padding(horizontal = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.margin_vertical_small))
    ) {
        Row {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.user_defined_car_battery_size),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
            )
            Image(
                painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_info),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable {
                        Log.d("Userdefinercarsxreen", "ButtonClicked")
                        onBatteryInfoCLicked() // <--- was misssing parenthesis
                    }
                    .padding(start = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.margin_vertical_tiny))
            )
        }
    }
```